# Dúvida preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex

Preciso fazer um `preg_match` para verificar se uma *string* atende às seguintes condições:

1. Iniciar com uma letra: `a-z`;
2. Conter apenas letras, número e os caracteres `,`, `.`, `-` e `_`;

Código atual:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}[a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9]/', $_POST['login']);
```

Comment: Se deve iniciar com uma letra, por que colocou `[0-9]{1,}` no início?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendimento:

> Iniciar com uma letra: `a-z`;

Deve iniciar com uma letra de `a` a `z` minúscula. OK!

> Conter apenas letras, número e os caracteres `,`, `.`, `-` e `_`;

Como não informa um número mínimo de caracteres após o primeiro caractere que é obrigatório ("*Deve iniciar com uma letra...*"), considera-se (pelo que entendi) que do segundo caractere em diante é opcional; mas se tiver, deve obedecer os critérios acima.

Logo:

Dentro dos critérios expostos na pergunta, você poderia usar esta expressão:

```
^[a-z][a-z\d_,\-.]*$
```

**Explicação:**

```
^             Delimita o início da string.
[a-z]         O primeiro caractere deve ser de "a" a "z" (minúsculas).
[a-z\d_,\-.]  Segundo caractere em diante.
              A partir do segundo caractere, pode ou não ter:
                 [a-z]  letras de "a" a "z" (minúsculas)
                 \d     números
                 _      underline
                 ,      vírgula
                 \-     hífen (escapado)
                 .      ponto
*             Quantificador que irá encontrar nada ou quantas ocorrências tiver
              a partir do segundo caractere.
$             Delimita o fim da string.
```

**Exemplo usando uma função:**

```
<?php
function checa($str){

   return preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z\d_,\-.]*$/', $str);

}

// 0 = false, 1 = true
echo checa("a"); // 1
echo checa("1"); // 0
echo checa("h1-11,11,"); // 1
echo checa("Aa"); // 0
echo checa("1abc_"); // 0
echo checa("aaaaaaaa"); // 1
echo checa("a-----,"); // 1
echo checa("a-12,_#,"); // 0
echo checa(""); // 0
?>
```

Para verificar, você pode usar um `if`:

```
<?php
if(checa("a")){
   // com o valor "a" irá entrar aqui.
   // significa que a string começa com uma letra minúscula
   // e atende ao critério da regex
   echo "passou";
}else{
   echo "não passou";
}
?>
```

> Lembrando que letras maiúsculas e acentuadas serão consideradas
>   inválidas.

Comment: Se não me engano, dentro de colchetes, o ponto não precisa de escape (`[.]` é o mesmo que `[\.]`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/FTKVXP/1/)), mas o hífen sim. Ou seja, `[,-\.]` é "o intervalo entre os caracteres `,` e `.`", que **coincidentemente** só possui o caractere `-` (além dos próprios `,` e `.`), [veja](https://regex101.com/r/DqJQLh/2/). Mas se trocar a ordem dos caracteres, o intervalo fica inválido e só vai funcionar se escapar o hífen: veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/DqJQLh/3) a regex inválida e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/DqJQLh/4) a versão corrigida, com `\-`

Comment: Verdade. Só precisaria escapar o hífen mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo seus parâmetros, fiz esse código:

```
$strings = array(
    'uma string inválida',
    'uma string valida',
    '0uma string invalida',
    'uma string invalida !',
    'uma-string_valida.',
    '@ uma-string_invalida.'
);

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^[^a-z]+|[^a-zA-Z\s\,\.\-\_]+/', $str))
        echo 'String COM caracteres inválidos: '.$str.'<br>';
    else
        echo 'String SEM caracteres inválidos: '.$str.'<br>';
}
```

Retorna:

> String **COM** caracteres inválidos: uma string inv**á**lida
>
> String **SEM** caracteres inválidos: uma string valida
>
> String **COM** caracteres inválidos: **0**uma string invalida
>
> String **COM** caracteres inválidos: uma string invalida **!**
>
> String **SEM** caracteres inválidos: uma-string_valida.
>
> String **COM** caracteres inválidos: **@** uma-string_invalida.

Repare na expressão regular (RegEx):

```
^[^a-z]+|[^a-zA-Z\s\,\.\-\_]+
```

Busco **qualquer coisa diferente de `a-z` no início da *string***:

```
^[^a-z]+
```

**Ou** (`|`)

**Qualquer coisa diferente dos caracteres:** `a-z`, `A-Z` (letras maiúsculas), `\s` (espaço), `,`, `.`, `-` ou `_`.

```
[^a-zA-Z\s\,\.\-\_]+
```

> Fora dos seus parâmetros, adicionei as letras maiúsculas e o espaço. Caso não queira, só remover da expressão regular: `^[^a-z]+|[^a-z\,\.\-\_]+`.